# How do I use a bash variable within sed command in this instance?

Tags: bash, sed

I want to insert a random number at the beginning of each line of a file (50 of them).

```
for i in `seq 1 50`; do
  r=$RANDOM
  sed -e '{$i}s/^/$r,/' file1 > file2
done
```

how do I get the i variable to work in that sed command?

Comment: use double quotes. Variable expansion doesn't take place in single quotes

Comment: Runnning that I get: "": command } expects up to 0 address(es), found 1"

Comment: That last one was on osx.  On an ubuntu box I get "sed: -e expression #1, char 4: `}' doesn't want any addresses"

Comment: because you have `{$i}` instead of `${i}`.

Answer (score 3):

If you use double quotes instead of single quotes it will expand bash variables, but then you'll also have to escape any bash special characters

You could do

```
for i in `seq 1 50`; do
  r=$RANDOM
  sed -e "${i}s/^/$r,/" file1 > file2
done
```

in fact, you could even do it without the intermediate var like

```
for ((i=1; i<51; i++)); do
    sed -e "${i}s/^/$RANDOM,/" file1 > file2
done
```

though be aware that file2 will only actually contain the last edit you make because you are overwriting it every time.

If you want to have all the edits in `file` you could use the `-i` flag.  With GNU's version you could do

```
for ((i=1; i<51; i++)); do
    sed -i -e "${i}s/^/$RANDOM,/" file1
done
```

then file1 would contain all the changes.

Also, you could do it with a single command without running `sed` for each with `awk` like

```
awk '{print int(rand() * 65536) ", " $0}' file1 > file2
```

which will give a random int between 0 and 65536, feel free to modify that int as you see fit.

Comment: +1 for the awk command and it's worth mentioning it'll get even more random if you add `BEGIN{srand()}` at the start to change the seed for `rand()` between awk invocations.